# CMake Linux - don't get executable

Tags: linux, docker, gcc, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm using CMake with Visual Studio 2019 to build an executable with the gcc compiler from a small C-program by using an Ubuntu in a Docker container. My problem is now, that I don't get an executable although I don't get any error during the building process.

A manual build on the command line with `gcc -o CMakeExec CMakeExec.c` works correct.

Here is my config:

CMakeExec.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
```

CMakeExec.c

```
#include "CMakeExec.h"

int main()
{
    printf("This is a test!");
    return 0;
}
```

First CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
add_executable (CMakeExec "CMakeExec.c" "CMakeExec.h")
```

Second CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project ("CMakeExec")
add_subdirectory ("CMakeExec")
```

CMakeSettings.json

```
{
  "name": "Linux-GCC-Debug",
  "generator": "Ninja",
  "configurationType": "Debug",
  "cmakeExecutable": "cmake",
  "remoteCopySourcesExclusionList": [ ".vs", ".git", "out" ],
  "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
  "buildCommandArgs": "",
  "ctestCommandArgs": "",
  "inheritEnvironments": [ "linux_x64" ],
  "remoteMachineName": "-970746741;localhost (username=test, port=5000, authentication=Password)",
  "remoteCMakeListsRoot": "$HOME/.vs/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/src",
  "remoteBuildRoot": "$HOME/.vs/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/out/build/${name}",
  "remoteInstallRoot": "$HOME/.vs/${projectDirName}/${workspaceHash}/out/install/${name}",
  "remoteCopySources": true,
  "rsyncCommandArgs": "-t --delete --delete-excluded",
  "remoteCopyBuildOutput": false,
  "remoteCopySourcesMethod": "rsync",
  "addressSanitizerRuntimeFlags": "detect_leaks=0",
  "variables": []
}
```

Dockerfile

```
# our local base image
FROM ubuntu 

LABEL description="Container for use with Visual Studio" 

# install build dependencies 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++ rsync zip openssh-server make 

# configure SSH for communication with Visual Studio 
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

RUN echo 'PasswordAuthentication yes' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && \ 
   ssh-keygen -A 

# expose port 22 
EXPOSE 22
```

Output from the Visual Studio

```
Copying files to the remote machine.
Starting copying files to remote machine.
[rsync] rsync -t --delete --delete-excluded -v -r --exclude=.vs --exclude=.git --exclude=out -8  "." rsync://test@localhost:51754/-home-test-.vs-CMakeExec-369e0150-0280-45f1-b4c9-244852742d47-src
[rsync] sending incremental file list
[rsync] CMakeSettings.json
[rsync] 
[rsync] sent 291 bytes  received 54 bytes  690.00 bytes/sec
[rsync] total size is 2,765  speedup is 8.01
Finished copying files (elapsed time 00h:00m:02s:371ms).
CMake generation started for configuration: 'Linux-GCC-Debug'.
Found cmake executable at /usr/bin/cmake.
/usr/bin/cmake -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="$HOME/.vs/CMakeExec/369e0150-0280-45f1-b4c9-244852742d47/out/install/Linux-GCC-Debug"  "/home/test/.vs/CMakeExec/369e0150-0280-45f1-b4c9-244852742d47/src/CMakeLists.txt";
[CMake] -- Configuring done
[CMake] -- Generating done
[CMake] -- Build files have been written to: /home/test/.vs/CMakeExec/369e0150-0280-45f1-b4c9-244852742d47/out/build/Linux-GCC-Debug
Extracted CMake variables.
Extracted source files and headers.
Extracted code model.
Extracted includes paths.
CMake generation finished.
```

I hope that anyone has an idea what is missing.

Comment: It doesn't look like the actual build command (ninja) was ran.

Comment: How can I get it to run? I installed it with `apt-get install ninja-build`.

Comment: What is the output when you hit "rebuild all"?

Comment: The "rebuild all" solved the problem. I'm sorry. Thanks a lot!